# Highcharts inverted column chart - descending tickPositions

Tags: highcharts

I would like my chart to start from a set threshold (3 in my example - the middle). If i set my tickPositions in ascending order ([1,3,5]) the chart displays fine.

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Cat1', 'Cat2']
  },
  yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [1,3,5]
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      threshold: 3
    }
  },
  series: [{ name: 'Demo', data: [2, 4] }]
```

But if i set my tickPositions in a descending order ([5,3,1]) it seems like the threshold gets ignored.

```
  yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [5,3,1]
  },
```

[JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pjuw5jce/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I would not specify the tickPositions out of order - it is not intended to work that way. Instead, specify them in the proper numeric order, and use the `yAxis.reversed` property.

Example:

```
  yAxis: {
    reversed: true,
    tickPositions: [1,3,5]
  }
```

Updated fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/pjuw5jce/4/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.reversed